# Composer and Google Auth JSON Key

Tags: php, json, session, authentication, google-cloud-storage

I need a sample code that shows me how I use the .json file I got from Google to authenticate that I am the owner of the storage Bucket.

Basically users upload their profile picture and I want to store it using Google Cloud, but every time I run the code below it says

> Could not load the default credentials

I have gone to the URL it gives and I get a 404 error.

My index file has this in it

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'sys/v1/core.php';
require 'sys/v1/google_cloud_storeage_upload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('/home/SITE/FOLDER/KEY-GOOGLE.json');

// $service implements the client interface, has to be set before auth call
$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { // logout: destroy token
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    die('Logged out.');
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) { // we received the positive auth callback, get the token and store it in session
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) { // extract token from session and configure client
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) { // auth call to google
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header("Location: ".$authUrl);
    die;
}
?>
```